# Dismiss multiple view controllers (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am facing one issue related to dismisscontroller(mentioned below) I tried resoving that issue  using `[self isBeingDismissed]` but didnt work for me.

Suppose we have **rootviewController** ->Presented **ViewController1** on that-> then Presented **ViewController2**

If you call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated of rootviewController then it behaves differently in iOS 8 and iOS 7.

1) In iOS 7 you go directly to rootviewController i.e. no methods from ViewController1 is getting called.
2) In iOS 8 first viewwillAppear of ViewController1 is getting called while dismissing.

Is there any other approach which can be used to resolve this? I have tried using

```
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed
- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your issue here... what is your problem you want to solve?

Comment: Out of interest, since `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is deprecated, does `dismissViewControllerAnimated:Completion:` have the same problem?

Comment: Yes @pbasdf, it does. Here is the same problem occuring in iOS8.4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396193/impossible-animation-with-dismissviewcontrolleranimated-ios8-4

Answer (score 0):

Although its not the most elegant solution, you could have a variable in viewcontroller 1 which is a boolean - dismissInProgress, then when viewcontroller 2 is about to be dismissed you could set this value on viewcontroller 1. Then you could have an if statement in the viewwillappear methods.

Another option would be, attach a navigation controller to viewcontroller 1, then when you present viewController 1, you actually present the navigation controller, then when viewcontroller 2 dismisses, it actually dismisses the navigation controller.