# Problems dismissing and representing UIImagePickerController camera iOS8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

**EDIT** Problem reinstated from scratch.

I have a `ViewController` **A** which has a Navigation Bar Button which presents an `UIImagePickerController` of sourcetype `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, we'll call this ViewController **B**. In the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method of **A**, I then present ViewController **C**.

The problem now starts here. When I finally reach **C**, we can see that view stack is clearly:

> **A** -modal-> **B** -modal-> **C**

From **C** I then have a "Back" button present on the navigation bar which should take me back to **B**. However, since **B** is an UIImagePickerController, I cannot reuse it and it must be dismissed. So, to make this happen, I currently have the following method executing for that "Back" button on **C**:

```
- (IBAction)backOnPost:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    UINavigationController *LogControl = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogControl"];
    RGLogViewController *logView = (RGLogViewController *)LogControl.topViewController;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
         self.presentingViewController.view.alpha = 0;
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [logView setBoolBackPushed];
    }];
}
```

The above code works in that it takes me back to **A** by dismissing **B** and **C**. However, you can still see the transition because of a bit of "black-screening" from the dismissal of the two ViewControllers. You can see in the completion block `[logView setBoolBackPushed];`, this sets a static BOOL variable to true so that the beginning of **A**'s `viewWillAppear:` presents a new `UIImagePickerController` immediately - the method looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"HERES postBackButtonPushed:%hhd", postBackButtonPushed);

    if(postBackButtonPushed == true)
    {
        self.view.hidden = YES;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

        UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:^{}];
    }
```

This is currently how I am getting the following desired effect:  Go from **A** to the camera (**B**), to **C** and then back to a new camera which is our new **B**. This is achieved w/ almost perfect **seamless** transitions.

Im still having problems with being able to slightly see the transitions. Another problem is the timing. This collaboration of dismissing and presenting ViewControllers takes more time than I would like it to. It's almost instantaneous, but I would like something better. What should I do and am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share a sample code in github ?

Comment: I cannot give you confidential project but I assure you the situation is exactly as I have explained it above. To test this, simply create a VC that presents a camera through a viewWillAppear of another VC, then try getting to the root VC with no animation problems as described above.

Comment: I was thinking about manipulating the stack of the views by removing the VC "B" once the VC "C" is displayed. I didn't ask for the code of the project, but just a sample project about what you tried to achieve

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do that because you would be dismissing the presentingViewController which would immediately dismiss C(not a desired effect). Also, I need B to be present for when the camera button 'Use Photo' is clicked because VC B is the next VC to use.. I only dismiss B when the user transitions from A->C which is what happens to begin with AND the user hits 'Cancel' on the camera View, which is VC B

Comment: `popToRootViewController`?

Comment: `[picker popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` does in fact, not work. I just tested it.

Comment: Isn't there a conceptual issue here, since dismissing B will reveal A, thus triggering a `viewDidAppear` in A?

Comment: It's better to upload an example project to Github or somewhere so we can easily find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Actually no Lancelot, I have a conditional that makes it reset so that the viewWillAppear only shows C once. There is only an animation problem, not a dismissal problem.

Answer (score 0):

there are some possible cases that cause your problem :

1. presenting B after A and then presenting C is a bit strange behaviour for both UX/UI and by code. Either push B from A and then present C over B OR dismiss A, present B, dismiss B, present C.
2. there are completion methods and you are not using them. your code show that you call dismissViewControllerAnimated twice for C and B for ex. you should handle presenting and dismissing order. I think iOS 8.2+ or 8.3+ start to handle them more efficiently. And if there is an error, it will crash after this version.
3. imagepicker controller cause this error while dismissing VCs in different ways. For ex. showing alert popup before presenting a VC can cause also a crash.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will work for you.
Do!

```
 [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
               [RefrenceOfPreviousViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

               }];
           }];
```

Instead of

```
 [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: This will dismiss the entire stack without an animation.

Comment: @Zorayr change `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO` to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES`

Comment: Then Use this deprecated method its working for me in iOS 10 `[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`